# C# multiple level generic types in interface

Tags: c#, generics

Saying I have the following interfaces

```
using System;

public interface IInput
{

}

public interface IOutput<Shipper> where Shipper : IShipper
{

}

public interface IShipper
{

}


public interface IProvider<TInput, TOutput>
    where TInput : IInput
    where TOutput : IOutput<IShipper>
{

}
```

I am able to create the following classes:

```
public class Input : IInput
{

}

public class Shipper : IShipper
{

}

public class Output : IOutput<Shipper>
{

}
```

I tried multiple ways to create a class implementing IProvider with no luck?

Ex:

```
public class Provider : IProvider<Input, Output>
{

}
Error: The type 'Output' cannot be used as type parameter 'TOutput' in the generic type or method 'IProvider<TInput,TOutput>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Output' to 'IOutput<IShipper>'
```

or

```
public class Provider : IProvider<Input, Output<IShipper>>
{

}
Error: The non-generic type 'Output' cannot be used with type arguments
```

How Can I do this?

Comment: To follow conventions, the `Shipper` in the definition of `IOutput<Shipper>` should be `TShipper`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to treat the generic argument `Shopper` in `IOutput` as if it's covariant.  You need to explicitly state that that generic argument is covariant when declaring the interface:

```
public interface IOutput<out Shipper> where Shipper : IShipper
{

}
```

(Notice the `out` keyword.)

Then the code compiles.

Note that after making this change you will no longer be able to use the generic type argument `Shipper` as parameters to any members of that interface; if it would be used in such a manor then the interface wouldn't be conceptually covariant.

You can actually simplify the code down a bit to remove some of the issues not relevant to this problem.  It all boils down to being able to do the following:

```
IOutput<Shipper> output = new Output();
IOutput<IShpper> = output;
```

That conversion is only valid if `IOutput` is covariant with respect to its generic argument.

Comment: Cant put it any better than this.